# Inverse Laplace transform of inverse function containing logarithm

Tags: logarithms, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of the following function but am currently stumped. My understanding is that I can't formally solve the integral because of the singularity at $s=0$, but I haven't found a way around that issue.

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left \{ \frac{1}{s \, (\mathrm{ln}\,s)^{2}} \right \}$

Apologies if this is a basic question. I'm trying to independently gain familiarity with Laplace transforms and don't have a network to ask. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Looks like: $$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s \ln ^2(s)}\right](t)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{t^{\sqrt{x}}}{2 \Gamma
   \left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)} \, dx$$ I doubt there's a closed form for the integral.